# Possible divisors of $s(2s+1)$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers, divisor-counting-function

I write $\psi(s) = s(2s+1)$ and let $d$ be the divisor function. If $s$ is prime then 4 divides $d(\psi(s))$. For example if $s=37$ then $d(\psi(s)) = d(2775) = 12$ and $4|12$. Is this trivial? I am not sure how to attack and prove this. Here is my approach:

Now I am thinking $d$ is multiplicative so we need to determine $d(2s+1)$.

***case 1***: If $2s+1$ is prime then $d(\psi(s))=d(s(2s+1))=d(s)*d(2s+1) = 2*2 =4$ and $4|4$.

***case 2***: $2s+1$ is not prime. This is where I am stuck. Now, $d(2s+1)$ is either even or odd. If it is even then $d(\psi(s))=d(s(2s+1))=d(s)*d(2s+1) = 2*2k =4k$ and $4|4k$ for some positive integer $k$. But if it's odd I am not sure of the next move. If it is odd and squarefree then $2s+1$ has an even number of divisors?

Is this the right approach or is there a better way to go about this? Also is the statement even true, is there a quick counter example? I want to go a step further and claim that $d(\psi(s))$ is equal to $4, 8, 12, 16, 20$ or $24$

Comment: Hmm? If $s=5$ then $2*5+1=11$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $s$ and $2s+1$ are relatively prime. Thus $d(s(2s+1))=d(s)d(2s+1)$.

Now suppose that $s$ is an odd prime. Then $d(s)$ is even.

We need to show that $d(2s+1)$ is even. Recall that $d(m)$ is odd if and only if $m$ is a perfect square.

If $s$ is odd, then it has shape $2k+1$, so $2s+1$ has shape $4k+3$. But no number of the shape $4k+3$ is a perfect square. Thus $2s+1$ cannot be a perfect square, and we are finished.

Comment: Yeah that looks good. I can show that $4k+3$ is square free. Any suggestions on the supplementary question? The only possible values are $4,8,12,16,20$ or $24$. For the case $4$ it is necessary for $2s+1$ to be prime?

Comment: What you need is not that $2s+1$ is square-free, but that it is not a perfect square. As to the conjecture that when $s$ is an odd prime $d(s(2s+1))$ is one of $4,8,\dots,24$, I am sure it is false.

Comment: Ok I am using the terms "square free" and "not a perfect square" incorrectly. Thank you for correcting me. Any counterexample to the conjecture would have to be a prime larger than $467$.

Comment: Indeed $d(2s+1)$ will be smallish for $s$ a smallish odd prime, so a hand search will not be very pleasant.  A program should find one quickly.

Comment: Well the smallest odd m d(m) > 12 would be $3^2*5*7*11$ so s =(m - 1)/2 > 1732.  I think...

Answer (score 1):

$d(n)$ is odd if and only if $n$ is a perfect square.  (Because if $a|n$ then $(n/a)|n$ so the divisors form distinct pairs ($a$, $n/a$).  These pairs are distinct so $d(n)$ is odd if and only if there is a factor such that $n/a = a$ i.e. $n = a^2$.)

If $2s + 1$ is a perfect square then $2s = a^2 - 1 = (a -1)(a+1)$ so as $s$ and $2$ are prime either:

$a-1 = 1; 2s = a+1 \implies a = 2; s = 1 1/2$ which is impossible.

$a-1 = 2; s = a+1 \implies a = 3; s = 4$ which is impossible as $s$ is prime.

$a-1 = s; 2 = a+1 \implies a = 1; s = 0$ which is impossible.

or $a-1 = 2s; 1 = a + 1 \implies a = 1; s = - 1/2$ which is impossible.

So $2s+1$ is not a perfect square and $d(2s+1)$ is even and $d(s(2s+1)) = 2d(2s+1)$ is divisible by 4.

As for the second  $797161$ is prime.  $2*797161 + 1 = 3^{13}$  So $d(797161*(2*797161 + 1)) = 2d(3^{13}) = 2*14 = 28$.  It was the third counter example I tried.

Comment: OK, that settles that. Thanks! I wonder if every number that is divisible by 4 occurs?

Comment: I would assume so.  Although I wouldn't have any way to prove it.  32413 is prime 2*32413 + 1 = 64827=27*49*49 which has 20 divisors.  So $\chi(32413)$ has 40 divisors.  I'm finding these by trial and error.

Comment: It would be interesting to show this, right? If $D$ is the set of all possible divisors of $\psi(s)$ with $s$ prime we have shown that $4$ divides every element of $D$.