# Possible divisors of $s(2s+1)$ follow up question.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisor-counting-function

This question is related to this post:[Possible divisors of $s(2s+1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700739/possible-divisors-of-s2s1).
I have some follow up questions which should be a new post.

I write $\psi(s) = s(2s+1)$. We showed that for every prime $s$ that $4\mid d(\psi(s)$. I falsey conjectured that $\psi(s)$ could only take on the values $4,8,12,16,20$ and $24$. Take for example the prime $797161$ then $d(\psi(797161) =28$. And so this lead me to ask the following questions:

> If $D$ is the set of all possible divisors of $\psi(s)$ does $D$
>   include every multiple of $4$? Equivalently if $D_{4m} = \{s|d(\psi(s) =4m\}$ is $D_{4m}$ empty for some integers $m$

Let $T$ be the table indexed in order column-wise with values from $D_{4m}$ then

$$ T =
        \begin{matrix}
        2 & 7 & 31 & 67 & \ldots\\
        3 & 13 & 37 & 97 & \ldots\\
        5 & 17 & 73 & 127 & \ldots\\
        11 & 19 & 103 & 199 & \ldots\\
        23 & 43 & 137 & 227 & \ldots\\
        29 & 47 & 139 & 229 & \ldots\\  
        41 & 59 & 181 & 241 & \ldots\\ 
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\\ 
       \end{matrix}
$$

Another way of looking at my question is asking:

> Does every column of $T$ have an entry?

Trivially $\bigcup D_{4m} = \text{PRIMES}$ - See Martin's comment below. In particular $T$ has infinitely many entries.

The entries in the first column of $T$ are the Sophie Germain primes.  None of the other columns of $T$ can be found in Sloane's database. None of the rows or diagonals are in Sloan's database either.

Comment: If I understand your notation correctly, how could $\bigcup D_{4m}$ *not* equal the primes? Any prime $s$ lies in $D_{d(\psi(s))}$. Are you trying to ask whether any $D_{4m}$ is empty?

Comment: Martin Thanks for pointing the obvious namely that $\bigcup D_{4m}$ are the primes - because I am considering every prime number. And yes I am asking if $ D_{4m}$ is empty for any $4m$ equivalently is every multpile of $4$ in the set $D$?

Comment: @Greg Martin. Then we know that order of $\bigcup D_{4m}$ is infinite.

Comment: It would be kind to readers arriving at this question if you were to restate your notation, especially your definition of $\psi$.

Comment: I will edit the question and thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably every $D_{4m}$ is nonempty, but I believe we can't prove it yet.

The "hardest" case is when $m$ is prime: we can only have $\psi(s)=4m$ if $d(2s+1)=2m$, and there are only two types of numbers with exactly $2m$ divisors when $m$ is prime:

- $2s+1 = pq^{m-1}$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes;
- $2s+1 = q^{2m-1}$, where $q$ is prime.

However, consider the polynomial $f(n) = (n^{2m-1}-1)/2$. It would follow from Schinzel's "Hypothesis H" that there are infinitely many primes $q$ such that $f(q)$ is prime. Then you can just take $s=f(q)$ for some such $q$, in which case $\psi(s)=4m$. (Indeed, this heuristic works for any $m$, prime or not.)

Comment: Maybe there is another approach? With that said it appears that if $s$ is in $D_{8}$ and if $s$ end in a $7$ then we have the primes $7, 17, 47, 107, 167, 197, 257, 317, 347, 557,...$ which are precisely https://oeis.org/A104164

Comment: Are there infinitely many primes congruent to 11 modulo 30? Is this true because of Dirichlet? It could be helpful.

Comment: Yes, Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions does tell us that there are infinitely many primes congruent to 11 modulo 30.

Comment: This could be a stretch but: $s$ prime and $f(s) = 2s(s-1)$. Suppose that $s$ ends in a 1 and that the greatest common divisor of $f(s)$ and $f(s+2)$ is $4$. I claim that $s$ are precisely the primes congruent to $11$ modulo $30$ and by Dirichlet there are infinitely many. I also claim that for any such $s$ that $s$ is in either $D_{4}$ or $D_{8}$. This is a "hunch" based on a few worked out examples and small values of $s$.

Comment: Neither hunch is correct. $\gcd(f(s),f(s+2))$ equals $12$ when $s\equiv1\pmod3$ and $4$ otherwise; so every $s\equiv11\pmod{30}$ has the properties you describe, and not all of those numbers are prime. Even if one restricts to prime such $s$, there are lots of examples that aren't in $D_4$ or $D_8$: the ones less than $10000$ are $1151, 2411, 2621, 2711, 3041, 3461, 3581, 4091, 4721, 4751, 5021, 5351, 5531, 6791, 7001, 7331, 8291, 8501, 9041, 9341, 9851$.

Comment: In general, there is *no* reason to suspect that a random arithmetic progression contains only numbers with a bounded number of divisors, even if you select only the ones that are $2$ more than a prime or some other additive condition. So I encourage you to be extremely suspicious of any future hunches that lead you to believe that only finitely many of the $D_{4m}$ appear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37201/discussion-between-anthony-hernandez-and-greg-martin).